# How to hide a panel that appears twice?

Tags: scripting, panel

I'm making an addon where I added a panel to a popover button. See the following example:
[image]
Here we can see (in image number 2) a popover button in Shadows. This panel is shown only on this button.

I managed to make this popover button as seen here:
[image]
Here is the code to exemplify what I did:

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )


class VIEW3D_PT_property_Group(PropertyGroup):

    show_statistics : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="show_statistics",
        description="Statistics",
        default = False
        )
    
class VIEW3D_PT_principal_panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Principal Panel"
    
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Panel"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.popover("VIEW3D_PT_popover", icon= 'PREFERENCES', text= "") 
                     
class VIEW3D_PT_popover(Panel): 
    bl_label = "Popover Panel"                             
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'                             
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Panel"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        propertyGroup = scene.property_Group
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("view3d.centermass", icon= 'NONE', text= "Origin Center Mass")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("view3d.origin", icon= 'NONE', text= "Origin To Geometry")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("view3d.move", icon= 'NONE', text= "Move")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(propertyGroup, "show_statistics", text="Statistics")

        if (propertyGroup.show_statistics == True):
            bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_statistics = True

        else:
            bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_statistics = False
      

class VIEW3D_PT_centermass(Operator):
    bl_label = "Button"
    bl_idname = "view3d.centermass"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {'EDIT_MESH'}, {'OBJECT_MODE'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')
        
        return {'FINISHED'}        

class VIEW3D_PT_origin(Operator):
    bl_label = "Button"
    bl_idname = "view3d.origin"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {'EDIT_MESH'}, {'OBJECT_MODE'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN', center='MEDIAN')
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
        
class VIEW3D_PT_move(Operator):
    bl_label = "Button"
    bl_idname = "view3d.move"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {'EDIT_MESH'}, {'OBJECT_MODE'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.move")
        
        return {'FINISHED'}        

classes = (
    VIEW3D_PT_property_Group, 
    VIEW3D_PT_principal_panel, 
    VIEW3D_PT_popover,  
    VIEW3D_PT_centermass, 
    VIEW3D_PT_origin, 
    VIEW3D_PT_move,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.property_Group = PointerProperty(type=VIEW3D_PT_property_Group)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.property_Group


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I could use an `invoke_props_dialog`, but a popover doesn't need to click "ok".
Would you know how to resolve this?
PS: My level in python and the blender API is embryonic.

Comment: Not completely sure what the question is here.  Suggest that your operator naming convention is a bit A about T. Consider using `FOO_OT_what_it_does`  --> `bl_idname = "foo.what_it_does"`.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it, thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome! You can select your code and press Ctrl+K to get it formatted properly. Please rephrase your question title back to english, thanks. Agree with batFINGER, not clear to me as well what your question actually really is, also I can not see any difference in the pictures that you've posted.

Comment: Please use english as language for your posts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Sorry for the title ... my browser translates automatically ... I didn't see it in my language.

The images were really the same .. it's my first post, sorry for the confusion! I hope I have fixed the problem.

About the images that I posted, specifically the second one, you can see that the panel that appears on the popover button, is the same one that is already appearing on the panel. I want this panel to appear only when I click the button.

Comment: I found the solution .. and it was very simple. Just use:
bl_options = {"INSTANCED"}.
The popover menu is just an instance of the panel.

Comment: @Nilson finally twigged re https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212463/how-to-register-a-popover-panel-that-doesnt-show-anywhere-else-in-the-ui  If you wish to add an answer will mark that a dupe of this, or not then this of that.