# How to register a popover panel that doesn't show anywhere else in the UI

Tags: python

I'm using
`layout.popover(my_panel)` to draw a panel in a box when it is clicked on, but I don't want that panel to be visible anywhere else in the UI. Just removing the `bl_category` setting from the panel class simply puts it in a category named "misc".

I realise that one solution could be to change the `bl_region_type` to something different, but if I change it to something like `"TEMPORARY"` it just gives me an error.

Is there a correct way to do this, or would it be better to do it from say the invoke method of an operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add `'INSTANCED'` to panel options**

Edit   Credit to [@Nilson](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207628/how-to-hide-a-panel-that-appears-twice#comment354130_207628)  *(finally twigged)*

[How to hide a panel that appears twice?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207628/how-to-hide-a-panel-that-appears-twice)

> I found the solution .. and it was very simple. Just use: `bl_options = {"INSTANCED"}`. The popover menu is just an instance of the panel

[image]

If the `'INSTANCED'` option is added to the panels [`bl_options`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_options)  the panel is not drawn directly in the UI, it is rather instanced via the popup call.

PLEASE Note. If the region is set to `'UI'` a "Misc" category tab is added, which when selected shows no panels (No others  in region and uncategorized) and  (for me) segfaults blender when selected.  The `'WINDOW'` region appears a safe bet.

Test script using the *`Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Panel Simple`* script modified to add to view3d UI (N) region. Making only the options edit confirms the panel no longer renders in the properties region.

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_options = {'INSTANCED'}
    #bl_options = {'INSTANCED', 'DRAW_BOX'}
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D' # 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    #bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.popover("OBJECT_PT_hello")
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_view3d_cursor.prepend(draw)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Tip. If you set an enum to a garbage value you can look at the error message to get allowable values:

```
TypeError: validating class: enum "FOO" not found in 
('WINDOW', 'HEADER', 'CHANNELS', 
'TEMPORARY', 'UI', 'TOOLS', 'TOOL_PROPS',
 'PREVIEW', 'HUD', 'NAVIGATION_BAR',
 'EXECUTE', 'FOOTER', 'TOOL_HEADER')
```

Fwiw `'HUD'` adds panel to operator redo panel.